# How to set values to "Manage Swatch(Values of Your Attribute)" section of swatch text attribute programmatically?

Tags: magento2, attributes, swatches

I have created a swatch text attribute. But the values are not getting saved properly. How to set values to the section "Manage Swatch(Values of Your Attribute)".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
        <?php
        if($_product->getManufacturer()){
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');//get current category

            $brand_value = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('manufacturer')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
            $brand_id = $_product->getManufacturer();
            $curnt_cat_url = $category->getUrl();
            $brandId = '?manufacturer='.$brand_id;

            $om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $swatchHelper=$om->get("Magento\Swatches\Helper\Media");
            $swatchCollection = $om->create('Magento\Swatches\Model\ResourceModel\Swatch\Collection');
            $swatchCollection->addFieldtoFilter('option_id',$brand_id);
            $item=$swatchCollection->getFirstItem();
            $ThumbImage =  $swatchHelper->getSwatchAttributeImage('swatch_thumb', $item->getValue());
            $SwatchImage = $swatchHelper->getSwatchAttributeImage('swatch_image', $item->getValue());

            ?>

            <div class="brand_bg">
                <a href="<?php echo $curnt_cat_url.$brandId; ?>" title="<?php echo $brand_value; ?>" ><img src="<?php echo $ThumbImage; ?>"></a>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php/***********End Brand Attribute************/?>
```